# IntelliSense based on "using" not inheritance

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the screenshot below compiler and IntelliSense show that unless I uncomment the `using` statement the `program` instance is not a valid argument to `SatisfyImportsOnce`. It's not matching signature based on base class/interface/implicit convert as far as I can tell and both have relevant references, so how does it know? What is this `using` check called and how is does it work?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fr8W.png

[image]

Comment: Depends. Is `SatisfyImportOnce(Program)` implemented as an extension method in the `System.ComponentModel.Composition` namespace?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah, forgot about extensions, didn't expect 'official' Microsoft library to use them. Yes, that's an extension method, thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised, LINQ is also an "official" MS library and uses extension methods all over the place :)

Comment: Well, sometimes it feels like extensions were specifically made for LINQ and its derivatives; and bypassing sealed classes. Was surprised to stumble upon one where a normal method [theoretically] would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the `using`, the compiler finds only [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.satisfyimportsonce%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in the `System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting` namespace, which only takes a `ComposablePart` parameter

With the using, it also finds [this extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd779466%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes an `object` parameter.